# Interpretation of Binary Logistic Regression

Tags: r, logistic

I am currently doing my master thesis and have difficulties fully understanding how to interpret the results of my binary logistic regression, since I have not a lot of experience with statistics.

Background info:

In Switzerland, almost all judges belong to a political party. I would like to analyze how this party political affiliation might influence the decisions judges take. Since my field of research is migration, I do this in looking at the decisions on asylum application appeals.

My dependent variable is therefore the decision (coded 0 for rejected, 1 for accepted). My main independent variable is the party political affiliation; i.e. the party the judge belongs to. The party political affiliation is coded as factor (i.e. actual party names). Furthermore, I have the control variables "Amtszeit" (duration in office) and "Geschlecht" (gender).

In the model, the reference level is a party called SVP. If I have understood it correctly, my results for the other parties are always compared to/in reference to the reference level.

```
Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 first_judge (Intercept) 0.1566   0.3957  
Number of obs: 19950, groups:  first_judge, 52

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -2.855990   0.143361 -19.922  < 2e-16 ***
SVP_BDP        0.608093   0.475874   1.278   0.2013    
SVP_CVP       -0.126424   0.221707  -0.570   0.5685    
SVP_FDP       -0.180926   0.234916  -0.770   0.4412    
SVP_GLP        0.681262   0.327020   2.083   0.0372 *  
SVP_Grüne      0.485510   0.287538   1.689   0.0913 .  
SVP_parteilos -0.007482   0.247983  -0.030   0.9759    
SVP_SP         0.498532   0.199631   2.497   0.0125 *  
Amtszeit       0.061837   0.008465   7.305 2.76e-13 ***
Geschlecht     0.176427   0.177060   0.996   0.3190
```

If we take the comparison of the parties SVP and SP, the log(odds) is 0.498532. If I convert this into odds and probability, I receive 1.6463 for the odds and 0.6221 for the probability. Here's my question:

Do I interpret the data correctly when I say that a judge from the party SP is 62% more likely to accept an asylum appeal if compared to an SVP judge? Or more general, an asylum appeal is 62% more likely to be accepted if it is decided by an SP judge rather than an SVP judge?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some promising threads: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5blogistic%5d%20interpret

Comment: If you are interested, interpretation becomes more intuitive if you play with predicted probabilities. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression

Answer (score 4):

You should read through some of the threads in @Sycorax's search to become more familiar with logistic regression.

You cannot convert the estimate for `SVP_SP` into an odds and a probability.  It is only a number in comparison to the reference category.  That is, `0.498532` is not the log(odds), it is the log(odds ratio).  The estimate for the intercept, `-2.855990`, is the log(odds) for `SVP`.  Thus, the odds a judge affiliated with that party, and who has 0 years of experience and is the reference level of gender, is 0.05749887, and the probability is 0.05437251.  If you exponentiate the estimate for `SVP_SP`, you get the odds ratio, 1.646303.  This tells you that a judge from `SP` (again with 0 years of experience and is the reference level of gender) has an odds 1.65 times higher than a judge from `SVP`, so the odds that a judge from `SP` approves an application is 0.05749887 x 1.646303 = 0.09466056.  Their probability of approval is then 0.08647481.  You can also get their odds (and ultimately probability) by summing the estimates before you convert: exp(-2.855990 + 0.498532) = 0.09466056.